# Count record based on dates like 0 to 7 days 7 to 14 days and 14 to 28 days

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a table having three columns `ID`, `status` and `CreateDate`. I want a count from the table based on createdate like

Last 0-7 days , 7-14 days, 14-28, and 28-35 days only...

Comment: Please post some data and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a sample table that looks like this:

```
SQL> select trunc(sysdate) today from dual;

TODAY
----------
21.08.2021

SQL> with temp as
  2    (select id, createdate, trunc(sysdate) - createdate diff_days
  3     from test
  4    )
  5  select * from temp
  6  order by createdate desc;

        ID CREATEDATE  DIFF_DAYS
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 20.08.2021          1
         2 19.08.2021          2
         3 13.08.2021          8
         4 12.08.2021          9
         5 02.08.2021         19
         6 26.07.2021         26

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

you could do it as follows (note that your periods aren't correct; the same row can't (or, should I rather say: shouldn't) belong to two periods. It can't be 0-7 and 7-14 if date difference is *exactly* 7 days. It is either in the first or in the second period, not both.

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select id, createdate, trunc(sysdate) - createdate diff_days
  3     from test
  4    )
  5  select
  6    sum(case when diff_days >= 0 and diff_days  <  7 then 1 else 0 end) " 0- 6 days",
  7    sum(case when diff_days >= 7 and diff_days  < 14 then 1 else 0 end) " 7-13 days",
  8    sum(case when diff_days >= 14 and diff_days < 21 then 1 else 0 end) "14-20 days",
  9    sum(case when diff_days >= 21 and diff_days < 28 then 1 else 0 end) "21-27 days"
 10  from temp;

 0- 6 days  7-13 days 14-20 days 21-27 days
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2          2          1          1

SQL>
```